# How can I bypass governmental censorship of certain websites, for instance in Iran?

Tags: proxy, vpn

I live in Iran and as you know there's a blocking system here. The people here use VPNs to access websites. I did the same. But days ago VPNs (PPTP, L2TP,SSTP) ports was blocked too. The alternatives was Freegate and free software similar to it. People mostly use these software in Windows. But I want a thing which supports Ubuntu too. Furthermore I know that port 443 is not filtered. Do you think is it possible to use OpenVPN in this situation?

Comment: Something interesting I struck that might be worth a look http://freecode.com/projects/ptunnel unless they even block pings or that website

Comment: +1 This question is relevant to a larger audience and deserves answers that can stand the time.

Comment: As a side note, Sina, your webpage as mentioned in your profile really is spam and should be removed if you ask me.

Comment: It's true I'm not professional blogger. But what's wrong with my blog !?

Comment: Ah interesting. If I click on your blog I get: http://worddictionary.com.au or groupon.

Comment: When I did the gudies here [link](http://www.cs.uit.no/~daniels/PingTunnel/index.html) `code` , I see this problem.

<<<  W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 082CCEDF94558F59
W: Failed to fetch http://www.cti.ecp.fr/~beauxir5/debian/binary/Packages  403  Forbidden
<hr/>
W: Failed to fetch http://www.cti.ecp.fr/~beauxir5/debian/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
<hr/>
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.>>>

Comment: My blog address is ok right now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7834/discussion-between-sina-and-private)

Comment: I don't know if OpenVPN would still work, but to test that you could give airvpn.org a try. They offer a guest account and also configuration files for openvpn (I've been using their (paid) service for more than a year now and am pretty pleased with it).

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of different ways to bypass government bans on websites. And one of them is **Tor Browser**.

Further information can be obtained from: [www.torproject.org](http://www.torproject.org)

And download options are here: [www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en)

EDIT:
Although it's fairly straightforward as this Tor Browser Bundled runs as a portable tool, a **PPA channel** might also come very handy, at least for automatic updates:

- https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/tor
- https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/tor64

Comment: Yes it does use 443 port which Sina says is open. Interesting article how Iran tried to block tor and how they got around it https://blog.torproject.org/blog/iran-blocks-tor-tor-releases-same-day-fix old article, still interesting

Comment: Honestly I did install Tor many times in ubuntu but I never was able to use it. Actually I always encounter with different problems.

Comment: I hope the ppa channel I've added above may overcome these problems, and you can mark this as Answered ;-)

Comment: @MeerBorg +1 It was really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

While Tor is an easy way, it is soooo slooow. The better one would be an SSH tunnel. Mass block of SSH is nearly equal to mass block of Internet. You can easily create your own SSH Tunnel gate on any server abroad that you own. There are even some [free](https://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Internet/Access_Providers/Unix_Shell_Providers/Free/) tunnel providers, but beware of scams.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly recommend you to install **Tor**. Because it is safer than VPNs and lots of people are using it around the world. So there will be lots of [documentations](https://tor.stackexchange.com/) to use.

You can run tor (not tor browser) on every browser you like and modify it as you want.

Just use the code below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor
```

You can just start a new session on your browser(for example: torify firefox) or  use extensions like *FoxyProxy*. Also I should mention that using extensions may put you at [security risks](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3239/tbb-foxyproxy-safe).